# double ampersand after a function

Tags: c++

I was looking through the documentation on `std::forward()`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward,  while I came upon this snippet:

```
struct Arg
{
    int i = 1;
    int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
    int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
};
```

What does the `&&` after `get()` mean? Is it similar to `int&& get()` ?